# Question: how would you have configured the default route?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a question what command would you use to configure the default route? I mean, I've tried: 
`ping 192.168.3.50
PING 192.168.3.50 (192.168.3.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.3.50: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.3.50: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.3.50: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms`

Then tried to configure the default gateway:

`ip route add default via eth3 peer gw 10.0.3.142 dev eth0`

but didn't work. :(

Here is my Network configuration:

`[root@host-0-0 /]# ifconfig -a
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.137  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 10.0.3.143
        inet6 fe80::19f6:e3d9:7122:9ccb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:89:00:03:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1069  bytes 121480 (118.6 KiB)
        RX errors 25  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 25
        TX packets 869  bytes 123920 (121.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

`eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8d3:43ff:fe9c:e9c2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:d3:43:9c:e9:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13  bytes 1026 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24  bytes 3797 (3.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

`eth3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.62  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 192.168.3.63
        inet6 fe80::af:97ff:fed7:9170  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:af:97:d7:91:70  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1600 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32  bytes 4419 (4.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

`lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

`virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:fb:c1:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

`virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:fb:c1:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Apparently the default route was already correctly configured, as the ping succeeded? You give no information at all about what your network configuration is, not even your own IP address.

Comment: @wurte So this command: `ip route add default via eth3 peer gw 10.0.3.142 dev eth0` should've worked according to you am I correct?

Comment: @wurtel here is my network configuration.

Comment: You don't show your existing routing; BTW, tip: use `ip addr show` instead of `ifconfig -a`, and use `ip route show` instead of whatever. As to your question: you tried to add the default route to interface `eth0` which you don't have; ir looks like you should use `ens3` which is in reach of your proposed default gateway.

Comment: Is eth3 a point to point link? I don't understand why you have `peer`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The question says: **If you were able to log onto 192.168.3.50, how would you have configured the default route?**

`ip route add default via [___________] dev eth0`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I was doing a Linux tutorial and it should've been in my list. When I click on the button [**Set up scenario**] it only gave me eth2 and eth3.

Comment: You're directly connected to 192.168.3.[48..63] on eth3, so no default route is necessary to get to 192.168.3.50. Maybe it's a trick question and the answer is "no default route is needed", or maybe the question is buggy.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It wants me to add a command to that blank question box.

Answer (score 1):

To make this the system default route just do:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.3.1
```

**But**, If you already have another default gateway just do:

```
ip route replace default via 10.0.3.1
```

To replace it.